# i want to change my status in database when user did something

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a requirement form in my application, and in that form, when the user inserts the requirements and then submit it, I send an email to a particular vendor.

What I want to do is, when the vendor sees that requirement, I want  to 
change the status from 0 to 1 automatically.

The code I have is this:

```
public function requirement()
{
   $data["msg"]="";
   $this->load->model('RequirementModel');
   $data['user']=$this->RequirementModel->getusers();
   $data['rolename']=$this->RequirementModel->getrolename();

   if($this->input->post())
   {
     $this->RequirementModel->add_requirement($this->input->post());
     $all_users = $this->input->post('user_id');
       foreach($all_users as $key)
      {
         $get_email = $this->RequirementModel->get_user_email_by_id($key);

         $role_name = $this->input->post('role_name');
         $vacancies = $this->input->post('vacancies');
         $experience = $this->input->post('experience');
         $jd = $this->input->post('jd');
         $hiring_contact_name = $this->input->post('hiring_contact_name');
         $hiring_contact_number = $this->input->post('hiring_contact_number');
         $config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://md-in-42.webhostbox.net',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'smtp_user' => 'test3@clozloop.com',
          'smtp_pass' => 'test3'
      );
         $this->load->library('email',$config);
         $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
         $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
         $this->email->to($get_email); 
         $this->email->subject('this is our requirements pls go through it');
         $link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin">Click Here</a>';
         $this->email->message($link);
         print_r($get_email);
         if($this->email->send())
         {
              echo "email sent";
         }
         else
         {
             echo "email failed";
         }
     }
  } 

  $this->load->view('Requirements/requirements',$data);
}
```

I don't have any idea how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What event occurs "when the vendor sees that requirement"? Is this when the email with the requirement is sent? Or, does the vendor need to do something else to acknowledge that they have seen the requirement in the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send requirement id in link sent to vendor as a query string.
For example -

```
$link = 'Click on this link - 
<a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login
/signin?requirement_id=1">Click Here</a>';
```

Now in your signin function update requirement id as below -

```
function signin()
{
    if( isset( $_GET['requirement_id'] ) )
    {
        // update requirement column here
        $this->db->where( array( 'requirement_id' => $_GET['requirement_id'] ) );
        $this->db->update( 'requirement', array( 'status' => '1' ) );
    }

    // your sign in code here
}
```

Now whenever vendor clicks on link and logs in status of particular requirement will be updated.

Comment: i have one doubt here u gave requirement_id is static..how should we give dynamically

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, to make requirement_id dynamic just pass requirement_id in the URL sent to vendor, you can get last created requirement_id by using `$this->db->insert_id();` just after you insert requirement in database.